# Complex form validataion in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, forms, angularjs

I am trying to do form validation with AngularJS. Validation method mentioned in [scotch.io](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-form-validation) is very helpful. In my form I have a drop down, based on selected option I need to do form validation and enable `submit` button.

Here is [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6nneA/3/). In fiddle I have shown only 2 drop-down, but I have 5 drop-down and each drop-down opens a form with 6 or more fields. I thought of working with `ng-required` but, expression size is getting too long. So, I cannot use `ng-required`.

How to do validation before submitting form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `paramForm.$valid` and  then put `ng-required="true"` or other validations on your form inputs. Then change your submit to this:

```
<form novalidate name="paramForm" ng-submit="paramForm.$valid && paramSubmitForm()">
```

The paramForm.$valid is also scope accessible, so you can rewrite your `paramSubmitForm()`
function to do:

```
$scope.paramSubmitForm(){
   if (!$scope.paramForm.$valid){
       return;
   }
   //submitting code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With complex validations I usually use `ng-disabled` on the `submit` button; I create a validation function that return `true` if the form is not valid and bind it to the `ng-disabled` attribute.

Something like:

```
$scope.validateForm = function() {
  /* return 'true' if  we want the button disabled */
};
```

and:

```
<form>
  <!-- all elements -->
  <button type="submit" ng-disabled="validateForm()">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```